# Nginx slow but server idle

Tags: nginx

For some reason we find nginx not capable of responding to standard files traffic.
The only solution we have found so far is adding more nodes, currently up to 23 VMs. However, none of the VMs are busy and the nginx is still not fully copping.

Our http and https services have not javascript, is just some PB of files that are accessible from all around the world, open data for omics stuff.

We don't have money for licenses, all is open source and so is the data, and I'm coming here with the hope that someone can tell us that we are making a huge mistake so we can fix it relatively fast and stop throwing more servers to this http service.

I'll show our config, the load when we distributed among 23 servers, then I'll focus the load on one server, and then I'll set it back to 23.

## Our config

```bash
[root@hlvlpxfer-http-ebi-002 nginx]# uname -a
Linux hlvlpxfer-http-ebi-002.ebi.ac.uk 5.4.17-2136.300.7.el8uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Fri Oct 8 16:23:01 PDT 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@hlvlpxfer-http-ebi-002 nginx]# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: OracleServer
Description:    Oracle Linux Server release 8.5
Release:        8.5
Codename:       n/a
[root@hlvlpxfer-http-ebi-002 nginx]# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.14.1
built by gcc 8.2.1 20180905 (Red Hat 8.2.1-3.0.1) (GCC)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1 FIPS  11 Sep 2018 (running with OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib64/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/uwsgi --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/scgi --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/run/lock/subsys/nginx --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_degradation_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_perl_module=dynamic --with-http_auth_request_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-pcre-jit --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-debug --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -Wl,-E'
[root@hlvlpxfer-http-ebi-002 nginx]#
```

### nginx.conf and conf.d/common*

```bash
 cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user nginx;

worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 999999;

#error_log /var/log/nginx/error-debug.log debug;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 32768;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format compression '$http_x_real_ip - $remote_user [$time_local] '
    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
    '"$http_referer" "$gzip_ratio"';

    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    log_format ebi-logs '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" ';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    chunked_transfer_encoding off;
    client_body_buffer_size 32k;
    client_body_timeout 11;

    # Gzip
    gunzip on;
    gzip on;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_min_length 10240;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon;
    gzip_vary on;

    keepalive_requests 100000;
    keepalive_timeout 30;
    open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_errors on;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    send_timeout 11;
    sendfile off;
    sendfile_max_chunk 512k;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 256;
    server_tokens off;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    server {
# SRA
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;
server_name ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk;

      access_log /var/log/nginx/xfer-ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk.log ebi-logs;
      include /etc/nginx/conf.d/common-server.conf;
    }

    server {
# Default
listen 80 default_server;
listen 443 default_server ssl;
server_name localhost;

      access_log /var/log/nginx/xfer-ftp.ebi.ac.uk.log ebi-logs;
      include /etc/nginx/conf.d/common-server.conf;
    }

}
[root@hlvlpxfer-http-ebi-002 nginx]# cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/common-server.conf
    root /xfer/public/;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/ftp.ebi.ac.uk.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/private/ftp.ebi.ac.uk.key;
    ssl_protocols        SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers          ALL:!aNULL:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;

    location /nginx_status {
        stub_status on;
        access_log off;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* "\.(json|txt)z$" {
        add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
        gzip off;
        types {
            application/json jsonz;
        }
    }

    location / {
        root /xfer/public/;
        autoindex on;

        max_ranges 30;
        sendfile_max_chunk 512k;
        sendfile on;

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,OPTIONS';
            #
            # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Accept';
            #
            # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            return 200;
        }
    }
```

### load (or the lack thereof)

```bash
[root@hlvlpxfer-http-ebi-002 nginx]# uptime
 20:54:26 up  3:56,  1 user,  load average: 0.04, 0.10, 0.09
[root@hlvlpxfer-http-ebi-002 nginx]# lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  1
Socket(s):           4
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
BIOS Vendor ID:      GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               58
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v3 @ 2.30GHz
BIOS Model name:     Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v3 @ 2.30GHz
Stepping:            0
CPU MHz:             2297.339
BogoMIPS:            4594.67
Hypervisor vendor:   VMware
Virtualization type: full
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            46080K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm cpuid_fault pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp fsgsbase tsc_adjust smep arat md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
[root@hlvlpxfer-http-ebi-002 nginx]# ps axu|grep nginx
root        9122  0.0  0.0 104148  2344 ?        Ss   17:37   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
nginx       9123  0.1  0.0 151264 26948 ?        S    17:37   0:12 nginx: worker process
nginx       9124  0.2  0.0 150544 26456 ?        S    17:37   0:24 nginx: worker process
nginx       9125  0.1  0.0 151388 27272 ?        S    17:37   0:21 nginx: worker process
nginx       9126  0.1  0.0 150656 26540 ?        S    17:37   0:12 nginx: worker process
root       39099  0.0  0.0 221924  1136 pts/0    R+   20:54   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

### nginx_status

```bash
[root@hlvlpxfer-http-ebi-002 nginx]# curl 127.0.0.1/nginx_status
Active connections: 14
server accepts handled requests
 11524 11524 33976
Reading: 0 Writing: 9 Waiting: 5
```

#### uptime and free

```bash
[root@hlvlpxfer-http-ebi-002 nginx]# uptime
 20:54:57 up  3:57,  1 user,  load average: 0.02, 0.09, 0.08
[root@hlvlpxfer-http-ebi-002 nginx]# free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       32560712     4267664      236280        9160    28056768    27854040
Swap:       2097148       12044     2085104
[root@hlvlpxfer-http-ebi-002 nginx]# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          31797        4175         250           8       27371       27192
Swap:          2047          11        2036
[root@hlvlpxfer-http-ebi-002 nginx]#
```

## Before applying load

```bash
[root@hlvlpxfer-http-ebi-002 nginx]# # No load
[root@hlvlpxfer-http-ebi-002 nginx]# echo "START"; date ; curl 127.0.0.1/nginx_status ; uptime ; free -m ; ps axu|grep nginx ; echo "END " ; date
START
Fri Jul 29 21:05:36 BST 2022
Active connections: 52
server accepts handled requests
 12161 12161 37508
Reading: 0 Writing: 16 Waiting: 36
 21:05:38 up  4:08,  1 user,  load average: 0.16, 0.20, 0.13
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          31797        4136         228           8       27432       27231
Swap:          2047          11        2036
root        9122  0.0  0.0 104148  2344 ?        Ss   17:37   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
nginx       9123  0.1  0.0 151264 26948 ?        S    17:37   0:13 nginx: worker process
nginx       9124  0.2  0.0 150544 26456 ?        S    17:37   0:26 nginx: worker process
nginx       9125  0.1  0.0 151388 27272 ?        S    17:37   0:21 nginx: worker process
nginx       9126  0.1  0.0 150656 26540 ?        S    17:37   0:13 nginx: worker process
root       40755  0.0  0.0 221924  1152 pts/0    S+   21:05   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
END
Fri Jul 29 21:05:38 BST 2022
[root@hlvlpxfer-http-ebi-002 nginx]#
```

## 5 minutes after applying load  (Load balancer focuses on only one server)

After a couple of minutes the LoadBalancer already starts finding the server 'not responding' and starts sending 'connection reset' to the clients. The load balancer is standard hardware which is checking the robots.txt file, and since nginx is not fast at giving it back it times out.

```bash
[root@hlvlpxfer-http-ebi-002 nginx]# sleep 240 ; echo "START"; date ; curl 127.0.0.1/nginx_status ; uptime ; free -m ; ps axu|grep nginx ; echo "END " ; date
START
Fri Jul 29 21:11:45 BST 2022
Active connections: 1588
server accepts handled requests
 15069 15069 38953
Reading: 0 Writing: 109 Waiting: 1479
 21:13:13 up  4:15,  1 user,  load average: 0.15, 0.11, 0.09
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          31797        4264         232           8       27300       27102
Swap:          2047          11        2036
root        9122  0.0  0.0 104148  2344 ?        Ss   17:37   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
nginx       9123  0.1  0.0 151264 26948 ?        S    17:37   0:13 nginx: worker process
nginx       9124  0.2  0.0 150976 26712 ?        S    17:37   0:26 nginx: worker process
nginx       9125  0.1  0.0 151388 27272 ?        S    17:37   0:22 nginx: worker process
nginx       9126  0.1  0.0 150656 26540 ?        S    17:37   0:13 nginx: worker process
root       41198  0.0  0.0 301520 16796 ?        S    21:08   0:00 python3 nginx_status.py
root       41343  0.0  0.0 301520 16860 ?        S    21:09   0:00 python3 nginx_status.py
root       41492  0.0  0.0 301520 16704 ?        S    21:10   0:00 python3 nginx_status.py
root       41927  0.0  0.0 301520 16740 ?        S    21:13   0:00 python3 nginx_status.py
root       41933  0.0  0.0 221924  1128 pts/0    S+   21:13   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
END
Fri Jul 29 21:13:13 BST 2022
[root@hlvlpxfer-http-ebi-002 nginx]#
```

Thanks for your time.

As requested, the VMs are have the following setup :

- 20VMs running kuberentes, traefik > nginx
- 3 VMs running nginx directly (OEL8.5)
- All nginx have the same configuration everywhere.
- Load balancer is F5 , distributing round-robin on all of them.

The 23VMs run on top of 3 Vmware hypervisors, the 3 VMs with OEL8.5 have affinity rules to run one on each hypervisor.

The Vmware cluster is not busy :

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v3 @ 2.30GHz

72 cores

[image: Vmware hypervisors under utilised]

Network for the hypervisors does not appear to be a problem:

1.
[image]
2.
[image]
3.
[image]

Comment: Please include more information about your hardware and virtualization environment. How many servers do you have, how many VMs are running on it, what's the load of the servers, how are the VMs and the servers specked, etc.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. The hardware has some load but I don't think is the bottleneck, I'll get all the possible details on Monday. Shall I be looking for some specific bottleneck?

Comment: We moved to apache, with the default apache configuration the same VM did 25x . We had 2 VMs side by side, nginx vs apache, and apache took 25x of the work, nginx load was still low, apache load was 3 on a vm with 4 cores.   It is obvious to me that our nginx configuration was the problem, but we will keep apache.